# How to rerender Fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, axios, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I've been trying for days to filter my fullcalendar and it still doesn't work properly. I've managed now at least to have 2 different calendars based on the page you are on (homepage or a different one with different events). So on the second one I have 2 dropdowns with lists. I've managed to pick the id of the selected item from the dropdown and I'm trying to give it as a parameter to my axios function so that the fullcalendar events has the json that I want. However if you change the type of the event (I have location as a type) then it doesn't update the change. So basically it initializes fine with the right events but if you have 2 types and want to change them from the dropdown it doens't do anything.

Here is the axios function:

```
events: async function () {
                if (window.location.href.startsWith(window.origin + "/Booking")) {

                    var data = await axios.get("/Booking/GetBookingsFiltered/", {
                        params: {
                            locationIDparam: locationSelected(), // doesn't update when you change it
                            carIDparam: carSelected(),
                        }
                    })

                    //calendar.events = data.data; some things I've tried and don't work
                    //calendar.rerenderEvents();
                    //calendar.render();

                    return data.data;
                } else { 
                    var data = await axios.get("/Booking/GetBookingsByUser/") // this works
                    return data.data;
                }
            }
```

In case you need the code for how I get the parameters:

```
function locationSelected() {
        var location = document.getElementById("location_filter");
        var selected_location = location.options[location.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log("You selected location: " + selected_location);
        return selected_location;
        //$("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent');
        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    }

    function carSelected() {
        var car = document.getElementById("car_filter");
        var selected_car = car.options[car.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log("You selected car: " + selected_car);
        return selected_car;
    }
```

I've tried using $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent');, $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvent'); $("#calendar").fullCalendar().render(); idk nothing I find online or in the documentation of fullcalendar work....please help

Comment: You must reload the list of events: Have you tried to recover your events? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents

Comment: Anything starting with `$("#calendar")` will not work in fullCalendar 4 because it's not a jQuery plugin. Any examples like that are referring to fullCalendar 3 (which was based on jQuery)

Comment: Anyway, you said _"However if you change the type of the event (I have location as a type) then it doesn't update the change"_ ...so, how are you handling the change of the dropdown list? All you should need to do is create a "change" event handler for the dropdown list, and then call `calendar.refetchEvents();` within that. That will run your "events" function, that will return the newly downloaded data to fullCalendar, and then it will draw them automatically. There's no need to call render functions etc.

Comment: I tried using the refetch events yes and it doesn't work idk if I use it wrong or what's going on...I tried calling the refetch events when the dropdown changes I tried writing it in the axios call and even made a "filter" button with a onclick function to call refetch events and it doesn't do anything

Comment: Wait so if i can't use $('#calendar') then how do I access the calendar ? do I really just write calendar.refetchEvents() ?